# Replacing a smart object in bulk with Photoshop script; Editing script for more than one smart object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

I found the following code and it works very well for most Photoshop files I have tried, but the file I want to use it with has 2 Smart Objects, one nested in the other. See attached images.

Is it possible to edit the code so it works with my particular file?

Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/laryn/0a1f6bf0dab5b713395a835f9bfa805c):

Thanks for the help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your original question on Stack Overflow you never mentioned that two SOs are nested. In this case I suggest to open a SO as a document with

```
function editSmartObject()
{
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    executeAction(sTID('placedLayerEditContents'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

If you're using only this particular file as an input your algorithm should be something like this I imagine in pseudocode:

```
var originaldocument = activeDocument,
    files = File.openDialog(...);

for file in files
    activeDocument = originaldocument; //selecting the original document
    editSmartObject() //opening SO for editing
    editSmartObject() //opening the second SO for editing
    // optionally remove a layer from previous iteration: activeDocument.activeLayer.remove()
    placeImage(file) //placing image to SO
    activeDocument.activeLayer.resize() //resize the placed layer if you need to
    activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES) //closing the second SO and saving changes
    activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES) //closing the first SO and saving changes
    saveJPG(); //save jpg with all the SO updated


function placeImage(imageFile)
{
    alert(imageFile);
    var desc554 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc554.putPath(cTID('null'), imageFile);
    desc554.putEnumerated(cTID('FTcs'), cTID('QCSt'), cTID('Qcsa'));
    var desc555 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc555.putUnitDouble(cTID('Hrzn'), cTID('#Pxl'), 0.000000);
    desc555.putUnitDouble(cTID('Vrtc'), cTID('#Pxl'), 0.000000);
    desc554.putObject(cTID('Ofst'), cTID('Ofst'), desc555);
    executeAction(cTID('Plc '), desc554, DialogModes.NO);
};

function editSmartObject()
{
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    executeAction(sTID('placedLayerEditContents'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
}
```